# How to increase Steam account inventory

Tags: steam

Recently I created a Steam account, purchased a $1 bundle from  https://www.humblebundle.com, and activated the games in this new account.
However, this new account only consists of 120 slots. If I'm not mistaken, a regular account should have 720 slots.
So my question is, how can I increase the inventory slots?

When I try to retrieve my profile info using the API (http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_570/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?SteamID=) it shows this:

```
{
"result": {
    "status": 1,
    "num_backpack_slots": 120,
    "items": [

    ]

}
}
```

Comment: Where do you see 120? Can you link to a screenshot?

Comment: Not sure how slots are gained, but games aren't part of the Steam inventory anyway, that's for stuff like TF2 hats

Comment: Perhaps you need to have bought a game off of the store worth a certain amount of money. I don't think it works like that but that's how it works for TF2.

Comment: @BenBrocka: That's not true every time. If he buys the games as gifts (and Humble Bundle makes it possible) your games are added as one item per gifted game.

Comment: When Valve say you need to purchase something to lift restrictions on your account (e.g. ability to use the community market), it means purchase something **from them**, not redeem codes from other sites.

Comment: @Trollwut Humble Bundle makes gifts into links now anyway so that's still not an issue for recent bundles

Comment: @BenBrocka It was never an issue, before they were links, they were keys. The only time Humble Bundle has added something to my inventory is when I redeemed the key for Toki Tori, which came with 3 coupons for Toki Tori 2+.

Answer (score 10):

In order to trade *any* items on Steam or use the Steam Market, you must [have activated Steam Guard on your PC more than 15 days ago](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1047-EDFM-2932) and own at least one non-free-to-play game.
There is an additional cooldown anytime you change your password or *(in the case of the market)* add a new payment method.

Once you are able to trade, **the size of your Steam inventory is unlimited**.

---

However, inventories for specific games can have additional restrictions.  For example, non-premium TF2 users cannot trade items they drop or craft, and have a 50-slot limit to their TF2 inventory.

You can become a premium TF2 member by buying an item at the TF2 store, or by trading for an [upgrade to premium gift](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Upgrade_to_Premium_Gift).  Your TF2 inventory size will then increase to 300, which can be increased up to 2000 using [backpack expanders](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Backpack_Expander).

---

> However, this new account only consists of 120 slots. If not mistaken, a regular account should have 720 slots?

The API you're using, `IEconItems_570`, is for [retrieving your Dota 2 inventory](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/WebAPI#List_of_IDs).  Until you buy a Dota 2 item from the Dota 2 store, **your Dota 2 account is considered free-to-play**.  Once you buy an item, your account will become premium and your backpack size will increase.

To retrieve your Steam backpack instead, use [Steam inventory REST call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393099/getting-someones-steam-inventory) instead.

Comment: +1 for pinpointing where OP went wrong, but I don't think `IEconItems_753` exists.

Comment: @lunboks Whoops you're right - I was going by memory, but was mistaken.  You need to use the *(non Web-API)* backpack call to get steam inventory.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Thanks for your detailed explanation. But few months ago, I tried to register an account for Dota 2(during Beta) and without buy any item, my inventory size is 720. Recently i tried to register another account again, and it become 120. Did i miss out anything?

Comment: @My2ndLovE Its likely that all accounts were considered premium during the DotA 2 beta.

Answer (score 6):

**Steam inventory space is unlimited.** I don't know where you heard 120 or 720 slots, but they are not correct. The [Trading Card Exchange Bot](http://steamcommunity.com/id/CardExchange) has almost 8,000 items in its inventory right at the time that this was written.

**Games on your account don't take up inventory space.** It's possible to obtain gift copies of games, which will be put in your inventory, but if you're just redeeming Humble Bundle links, you don't have to worry about that. Redeemed games will go into your library, which is also unlimited.

Edit:

Based on the API call that you posted, you're looking at your DotA 2 inventory, not your Steam inventory. DotA 2, and several other Valve games, have a "backpack" contains items that can be traded on the Steam marketplace, and therefore show up in your Steam inventory. This information should not concern you if you're just adding games from a Humble Bundle to your account.

Comment: I retrieve my profile inventory slot using steam api and it show 120. Please refer my edited post.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I added an edit to my response, although it seems BlueRaja beat me to it. My bold sentences still answers your question most directly, but at least now we know where the confusion came from, and what those numbers really mean.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, steam general inventory slot is unlimited.

Keep in mind game inventory is separated from general inventory. For example, inventory of DotA 2 contains things like wearable items, couriers, gems, and chests. By default it can hold 720 items at maximum, and can be expanded up to 2400.

Another example is Team Fortress 2, free account has only 50 inventory slot. Purchasing Orange Box(a Valve bundle), or any goods from Mann Co. Store will upgrade your account to premium. Premium account has 300 inventory slot and can be expanded up to 2000 using expansion tool.

> But few months ago, I tried to register an account for Dota 2(during Beta) and without buy any item, my inventory size is 720. Recently i tried to register another account again, and it become 120. Did i miss out anything?

These are few possible reasons I can think of:

1. Steam set newly made account to 120 slots to save their storage, once your inventory is holding * amount of item it will be automatically updated. It seems small about 600 inventory slots, which may take up 10KB spaces. But Steam is getting a lot of new account every day, and some of them are bot, or account that will never be used again. So it might not a good idea to waste 10KB of spaces for every inactive accounts.
2. Steam API is showing wrong information, or we read it wrong. However I can never make that API work for me so I couldn't test for you.

If you believe your account is really into problem and not having reasonable slots, I would suggest you to go to Steam Forum and ask some people who can actually help you. Because we are not helping anything overall...Good luck!

I am sorry for my bad English but hopefully this could answer your question.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, DotA 2's inventory is limited too, I will edit my answer now.

Comment: I've never heard anyone claim steam inventory is limited.  It is not.  And leveling up your account has nothing to do with your inventory space.  -1

Comment: Yeah -1, give a source for your outlandish answer.

Comment: You look angry, I will just edit my answer to my original one then.

Comment: @008 Thanks for your detailed explanation. But few months ago, I tried to register an account for Dota 2(during Beta) and without buy any item, my inventory size is 720. Recently i tried to register another account again, and it become 120. Did i miss out anything?

Comment: Answered @My2ndLovE's comment

Answer (score -4):

### TL;DR By combining trading cards to badges.

First of all your games are not stored in your inventory, so this amount will not be touched. Exception: If you add them as presents, every present is one item.

If you still need more place in your inventory (maybe because you collect a huge amount of ingame items from Team Fortress 2, Dota 2, CS:GO and so on), you have to collect [Steam Trading Cards](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq?l=english).

Nowadays many games do have trading cards available. After an amount of playing time of a game (mostly about 30-60 minutes) you get 1 trading card. In the most cases you can't get more then [Half of all trading cards]+1 for one game, for which you have to trade with others.

Another option would be buying them on the [Steam Communiy Market](http://steamcommunity.com/market/). You can buy from any game, as creating badges and collecting cards is NOT limited to games you own.

If you have a complete set of trading cards, you can then create a so-called badge out of them. You can look at your progress of collecting cards and create badges using the following site:

```
http://steamcommunity.com/id/YOUR_STEAM_COMMUNITY_ID/badges/
```

Just replace the ID with your own.

If you create one of those badges, you mostly get:

- Experience points
- One smiley of that game
- One community background of that game
- Sometimes a coupon for another game

With that Experience Points, you can increase in level. In the first levels one badge means one level. And every level your inventory size is increased.

Comment: Where does it say that Steam levels expand your inventory?

Comment: Oh nooooez... me idiot! I mixed it up with friend list slots. I guess you get more inventory pages when you once bought an item from the market, but I need to investigate this.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your answer first.

Comment: Why editing? For now it's totally misleading, I'm thinking about deleting. :/

Comment: I heard some people say Steam level affects inventory slots too, but I couldn't find any prove. Not even Steam staffs/documents have explain about inventory slots.

Comment: @008 Those people probably made the same honest mistake that Trollwut did.